# is it possible to upload new apk with different private key ? google play beta

Tags: android, google-play, private-key

In google play [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213), it says that:

> You don't need a production APK to publish an alpha/beta app

That's mean I can upload an APK signed with different private key. Right?

But when i try that i got this error:

> You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to
>   disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn
>   more about debuggable APKs. You uploaded an APK that is signed with a
>   different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same
>   certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s)
>   with fingerprint(s):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's mean I can upload an APK signed with different private key.
>   Right?

No, that's mean that you can upload a beta or alpha without have an APK in production. For example if you want to test your app before going into production you can publish a beta app and understand if there are any problems.

Once you publish an APK (alpha, beta, production) you need to use the same certificate.